# What is input (and shape) to K/V/Q of self-attention of EACH Decoder block of Language-translation model Transformer's tokens during Inference?

Tags: transformer, attention, machine-translation, language-model, encoder-decoder

Transformer model of the original [Attention paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) has a decoder unit that works differently during Inference than Tranining.

I'm trying to understand the shapes used during decoder (both self-attention and enc-dec-attention blocks), but it's very confusing. I'm referring to [this link](https://towardsdatascience.com/transformers-explained-visually-part-1-overview-of-functionality-95a6dd460452) and also the original [Attention paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762)

In Inference, it uses all previous tokens generated until that time step (say `k`th time-step), as shown in the diagram below and explained at [this link.](https://towardsdatascience.com/transformers-explained-visually-part-1-overview-of-functionality-95a6dd460452)

[image]

Another diagram that shows self-attention and enc-dec-attention within decoder:

[image]

**Question:**

However when I look at actual shapes of the QKV projection in the decoder self-attention, and feeding of the decoder self-attention output to the "enc-dec-attention"'s Q matrix, I see only 1 token from the output being used.

Let's **assume 6 deocder blocks one after the other in the decoder stack** (which is the base transformer model).

I'm very confused how the shapes for all matrices in the **Decoder blocks after decoder-1** of the decoder-stack (more specifically decoder-block-2 decoder-3, decoder-4..., decoder-6 of the decoder stack) self-attention and enc-dec-attention can match up with variable length of input to the decoder during inference. I looked at several online material but couldn't find answer.
I see only the BGemms in the decoder's self-attention (not enc-dec-attention) using the variable shapes until all previous `k` steps, but all other Gemms are fixed size.

- How is that possible? Is only 1 token (last one from decoder output) is being used for qkv matmuls in self-attention and Q-matmul in enc-dec-attention (which is what I see when running the model)?
- Could someone elaborate how all these shapes for QKV in self-attention and Q in enc-dec-attention match up with decoder input length being different at each time-step?**

Comment: Hello. Rather than saying that you're confused in the title, could you please put your **specific** question there? Thanks!

Comment: Updated to specific question in the title per your comment.

Comment: Please see [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/40179/how-does-the-decoder-only-transformer-architecture-work) (newer) post for an answer to your question